# CheckBox and JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create javascript code that will save all checkbox that user clicked and when user click on button finish, code will show him what he chose.(Text in label )

Honestly I do not have an idea and need help.

Is that possible to achieve on this way :

```
<html>
<script>
   function test()
   {

      if(document.getElementById("chk").checked)
      {    
        // save in some variable nad print on the end.. That is my problem.. and i have no idea. 
      }
   }
</script>

    <body>
       <input type="checkbox" id="chk">
           <label>someTXT</label>
           <input type="button" onclick="test();"></input>
       </input>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'save' do you want to put it in a database? Or do you only want to 'save' it to show it in the label while the user is on the page?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/W4sjA/

Comment: Well i want to put it in email.. When he clicked on all checkbox-es then user click on send and he send me mail. But now it would be nice if I could just display it somewhere .. It can be with alert () functio too..

Comment: Thank you Krishna. I hope that this will work :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exmaple to return all checked checkboxes (if you have more than one):

```
test = function() {
var checkboxesIDs = '';
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for (var i=0; i<inputs.length; i++) {
     if (inputs[i].type == "checkbox") {  
         if(inputs[i].checked == true) {
            checkboxesIDs+= inputs[i].id +", ";             
         }
     }
}
alert(checkboxesIDs);
}
```

and HTML:

```
<input type='checkbox' id='c1' />
<input type='checkbox' id='c2' />
<input type='checkbox' id='c3' />
<input type='checkbox' id='c4' />
<input type='button' onclick="test();" value="Test" />
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/47EdX/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a short example that figure out how to get this:

**JS Function to check through checkboxes:**

```
function checkAll(bx) {
  var cbs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
  for(var i=0; i < cbs.length; i++) {
    if(cbs[i].type == 'checkbox') {
      cbs[i].checked = bx.checked;
    }
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="checkAll(this)">
```

You have to complement with some Array or object that will stores some value to push into the server.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input[type='button']").click(function(){
  $cb = $("input[type='checkbox']").prop("checked");
  $cb.each(function(){
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
  });
});
```

That's the way to access ALL checkboxes on your page and popup each id. You can also show any other attribute of your checkboxes like value or name.